# Select distinct only selects single column

Tags: c#, linq, distinct-values

Based on this question:

[How can I do SELECT UNIQUE with LINQ?

I wrote the below expression to select rows with unique `OrganizationID` column from the `dt` datatabe which contains multiple columns.

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows
                    select new { col1 = dRow["OrganizationID_int"] }).Distinct();
```

but when I check `distinctRows` after the expression being executed, it only has records with 1 column (`col1`) instead of holding the whole columns. I afraid that adding expressions like `col2=...` and etc, may be interpreted that I want select distinct on all these columns.

So how can I get the whole row while applying unique filter on only 1 column but not the whole columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Could you paste some sample data?

Comment: Which row do you want to keep in case of multiple rows with the same `OrganizationID_int`, the first, last, oldest, newest, highest,...?

Comment: @Tim: I want the whole rows which satisfy that unique condition with all columns. I want to iterate in the next step.

Comment: @Farshid: So you just want the rows which are unique and you don't want to group by that field, is that correct?

Comment: @Farshid: Added an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13585738/284240

Comment: @Tim. Group by is OK. I just want rows with a unique value in a special column (OrganizationID_int).

Comment: @Farshid: Yes and i have already given you the answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want the whole rows which satisfy that unique condition with all
>   columns. I want to iterate in the next step.

So you don't want to group by that field and return one of the multiple rows. You want only rows which are unique.

One way is using `Enumerable.GroupBy` and count the rows in each group:

```
var uniqueRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("OrganizationID_int"))
                   .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                   .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: g.First() causes that only one row is placed in uniqueRows. Can you please suggest a way I get the whole rows instead of only first? I need to iterate among the uniqueRows at the second step.

Comment: @Farshid: This code will return all unique rows not only the first. The `GroupBy` can return mulitple rows, but since i've used `Where` to count the group i have ensured that only one row is contained. That also means that this `OrganizationID_int` is unique across the whole `DataTable`. However, you need the `First` because you want to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` as result.

Answer (score 1):

There is two versions of [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) exception methods, one of them takes [IEqualityComparar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.aspx) that can determine how you're going to distinguish different elements.

Here full example of how you can use this method:

```
class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item x)
    {
        return x.Id;
    }
}

void Main()
{
  var sequence = new List<Item>() 
  {
      new Item {Id = 1, Name = "1"}, 
      new Item {Id = 1, Name = "2"}
  };

  // Using overloaded version of Distinct method!
  var distinctSequence = sequence.Distinct(new ItemComparer());

  // distinctSequence contains inly one Item with Id = 1
  distinctSequence.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `GroupBy`, followed by an aggregate function like `Min`, `Sum`, etc to select one of the row values for each column.

```
var distinctRows = 
    (from DataRow dRow in dt.Rows
    group dRow by dRow["OrganizationID_int"] into g
    select new { OrgId = g.Key; Col2 = g.First().Col2, Col3 = g.First().Col3 })
```

Comment: Could just `select g.First` rather than try to replicate it in an anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping with Linq to DataSet:

```
var distinctRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   group row by new { 
                      col1 = row.Field<int>("OrganizationID_int")
                      // other columns here 
                   } into g
                   select g.First();
```

Comment: He want unique rows so rows where `OrganizationID_int` are unique.

Comment: @Sergey: I do not want one row at once. I want whole rows.

Comment: @Farshid this query returns all distinct rows (not unique, but distinct) - first row, which have unique set of column values is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *MoreLinq*'s [`DistinctBy` method](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307), with which you can phrase your query like so:

```
dt.Rows.DistinctBy(dRow => dRow["OrganizationID_int"])
```